# How can I disable other checkboxes(Dynamically Created) if I checked one?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I disable other checkbox if I clicked one I..e dynamically created checkbox using `input type=checkbox`

```
@if (ViewBag.Products != null)
{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Products)
    {
        <label class="PillList-item">
            <input id="Check" type="CheckBox" name="@item.ProductID"/>
            <span class="PillList-label" >
                @item.Products
                <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
            </span>
        </label>
    }
}
```

Comment: Which you want? Disable other checkboxes or select only one checkbox.

Comment: Disable other checkboxs if click one checkbox from the generated checkboxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
@section Scripts{
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
                    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                });
            });
           
        </script>
    }
```

Comment: Still Not working

Answer (score 0):

First Update the dynamic checkbox code with addition of 'chkInfo' as class value i.e.

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.Products)
{
    <label class="PillList-item">

        <input id="Check" type="CheckBox" name="@item.ProductID" class="chkInfo" onclick="Javascript:{UncheckAll_js(this)}"/>

        <span class="PillList-label" >

            @item.Products

            <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

         </span>
    </label>
}
```

Then using Java Script as below uncheck all the unwanted checkboxes i.e.

```
// Global variable to access jQuery method from JavaScript method.
var uncheckAll_jq;

// jQuery method goes here.
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    // This method will disable all the check boxes except the one which is checked
    uncheckAll_jq = function UncheckAll(currentCheckBox) 
    {
        // First unchecheck all
        $(".chkInfo").removeAttr('checked');

        // Then check your target checkbox as already checked.
        $(currentCheckBox).attr("checked", true);
    }
});

// JavaScript codes goes here.
function UncheckAll_js(currentCheckBox_info)
{
   // Invoke jQuery Method.
   UncheckAll_jq(currentCheckBox_info);
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Js function is declared but its  value is never read for UncheckAll function. Click event is not a part of input type=checkbox

Comment: I have updated my answer it's onclick not click in the input tag. Try with that.

Comment: Also, you need to make JavaScript wrapper to access jQuery method. I have updated that as well.